# Read CSV File and store data in the dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 15 columns.I want to read the csv and make a python dictionary that consists of first column as a key and remaining columns as a value in the form of a list.Each key in the dictionary should be a string.
But i have no idea to make the all values as a python list.

```
import csv

mydict = {}

with open('Emissions.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    dict_from_csv = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

print(dict_from_csv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dict_from_csv = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in reader}
```